# compare lists using wild cards

Tags: list, recursion, lisp

I am trying to write a function which compares two lists for homework. When the function run it should be something like this  ;(cmp ‘(cat ?x mat ?x) ‘(cat bat mat bat))  =>  t  ;(cmp ‘(cat ?x mat ?x) ‘(cat bat mat sat))  =>  nil.  meaning that in the first list when equal to ?x and the second ?x return true if both are pointing to the same value.
When I run the program now is giving me  "error while parsing arguments to special form if: invalid number of elements" Here is my code if you can give me some feedback. Thanks.

```
;cmp algorithm
;1 if the both lists are empty return true
;2 if only one of the lists is empty return fasle
;3 compare first of the list1 and the first of list2
;if equal go on to the rest of the list with recursive call else return false   

(defun cmp (list1 list2)
(setq y '())
(setq z '())
(defparameter *counter* 0)
  (cond 
   ((and (null list1) (null list2))
    t 
    )
   ((or (null list1) (null list2))
    nil
    )
    ((or (eq (first list1) (first list2)) 
         (eq (first list1) '?x)  )
     (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2) )

        ;if (first list is equal to '?x)
        ;set the counter to 1
        ;give the value of (first(rest list2)) to y 
        ;if (first list is equal to '?x) again
        ;set the counter to 2
        ;give the value of (first (rest list2)) to z
        ;i need to compare y and z if eq return true

     (if (eq (first list1) '?x) 
        (princ (first list1 ))
        (princ (first(rest list2)))

        (1+ *counter*)
        (set y (first(rest list2)))

        (if (= *counter* 2)
        (set z (first (rest list2)))    
            )       
        )

        (if (= y z) t)      
     )
   (t
    nil)
   )
  )





;(cmp ‘(cat ?x mat ?x) ‘(cat bat mat bat))  =>  t 
  ;(cmp ‘(cat ?x mat ?x) ‘(cat bat mat sat))  =>  nil
```

Comment: I propose that you read a book on Lisp. Here is a free one: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/ . Check how local variables are defined in Lisp. Also check the syntax of IF in Lisp and compare that with the use of IF in your code: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm

Comment: I propose that you learn how [to format Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) if you want some help from Lisp programmers. I for one, won't even bother reading your question. (I also wish that the experienced Lispers here insisted on that, but either they've given up, or a few points here and there make them ignore this mess.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You're missing how to match generically on any symbol whose first character is `?` and how to pass matches to recursive calls.

You need to save your matches somewhere between calls. A possible approach is pass them in an optional [association list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_aba.htm) of matches:

```
(defun cmp (list1 list2 &optional matches)
  (cond ((and (null list1) (null list2))
         t)
        ((or (null list1) (null list2))
         nil)
        ((and (symbolp (first list1))
              (plusp (length (symbol-name (first list1))))
              (eql (char (symbol-name (first list1)) 0) #\?))
         (let ((assoc (assoc (first list1) matches)))
           (cond ((null assoc)
                  (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2)
                       (list* (cons (first list1) (first list2))
                              matches)))
                 ((eql (cdr assoc) (first list2))
                  (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2) matches)))))
        ((eql (first list1) (first list2))
         (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2) matches))))
```

A very similar approach to this one which uses a [dynamic variable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abaab.htm):

```
(defvar *matches* '())

(defun cmp (list1 list2)
  (cond ((and (null list1) (null list2))
         t)
        ((or (null list1) (null list2))
         nil)
        ((and (symbolp (first list1))
              (plusp (length (symbol-name (first list1))))
              (eql (char (symbol-name (first list1)) 0) #\?))
         (let ((assoc (assoc (first list1) matches)))
           (cond ((null assoc)
                  (let ((*matches* (list* (cons (first list1) (first list2))
                                          *matches*)))
                    (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2))))
                 ((eql (cdr assoc) (first list2))
                  (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2))))))
        ((eql (first list1) (first list2))
         (cmp (rest list1) (rest list2)))))
```

Both could be called this way:

```
> (cmp '(?x b ?x d ?y f ?y h)
       '(a  b c  d  e f g  h))
nil
> (cmp '(?x b ?x d ?y f ?y h)
       '(a  b a  d  e f e  h))
t
```

However, if you already start with an association list of matches, the first one is called like this:

```
> (cmp '(?x ?y)
       '(a  b)
       '((?x . a)))
t
```

While the second one is to be used like this:

```
> (let ((*matches* '((?x . a))))
    (cmp '(?x ?y)
         '(a  b)))
t
```

---

Exercise: Make `cmp` always match `'?` (a symbol whose name is solely the question mark) to anything.

This may be useful if you want an element to be there but you want to ignore it otherwise.

---

Exercise: Make `cmp` more useful and return the list of found associations instead of `t`:

```
> (cmp '(?x ?y)
       '(a  b))
((?x . a)
 (?y . b))

;;; Assuming option one
> (cmp '(?x ?y)
       '(a  b)
       '((?x . a)
         (?z . c)))
((?x . a)
 (?y . b))
> (cmp '(?x ?y)
       '(c  b)
       '((?x . a)
         (?z . c)))
nil
```

The idea is to return only the found associations, and not the unused ones. So, even though the second test returns non-`nil`, `?z` doesn't appear in the result.

Answer (score 2):

While reading the book or documentation will certainly help, sometimes looking at example code, especially after you already understand the problem can help too. So here's an unpretentious straight-forward solution:

```
(defun compare-using-wildcards (pattern matched)
  (loop for p in pattern
     for m in matched
     with keys = (make-hash-table)
     do (unless (eql p m)               ; Doesn't matter
                                        ; if it starts with ?
                                        ; we still don't consider
                                        ; it a wildcart symbol, if
                                        ; it matches the symbol in
                                        ; the other list.
          (if (and (symbolp p)
                   (char= (aref (symbol-name p) 0) #\?))
              (multiple-value-bind (registered exists)
                  (gethash p keys)
                (if exists
                    (unless (eql registered m)
                      (return))
                    (setf (gethash p keys) m)))
              (return)))
     finally (return t)))

(compare-using-wildcards '(cat ?x mat ?x) '(cat bat mat bat)) ; T
(compare-using-wildcards '(cat ?x mat ?x) '(cat bat mat sat)) ; NIL
(compare-using-wildcards '(cat ?x mat ?y) '(cat bat mat sat)) ; T
(compare-using-wildcards '(cat ?x max ?y) '(cat bat mat sat)) ; NIL
```

But there are lots and lots of ways to do this! For example, if lists are known to be short, it could be feasible to do this via `destructuring-bind`. Alternatively, you could've written a "zip" function (a higher order function that feeds cells from multiple lists to other function until it returns non-nil result) and so on.

---

And a somewhat contrived example. Well, it looks like it should work, unless I'm missing some corner case. It would compare multiple lists against the list with wildcards:

```
(every (let ((keys (make-hash-table)))
       #'(lambda (&rest elements)
           (let ((wildcard (car elements)))
             (if (and (symbolp wildcard)
                      (char= (aref (symbol-name wildcard) 0) #\?))
                 (let ((replacement (gethash wildcard keys))
                       (i -1))
                   (if replacement
                       (every #'(lambda (x)
                                  (eql x (aref replacement (incf i))))
                              (cdr elements))
                       (setf (gethash wildcard keys)
                             (coerce (cdr elements) 'vector))))
                 (every #'(lambda (x) (eql x wildcard)) elements)))))
     '(cat ?x mat ?x)
     '(cat bat mat bat)
     '(cat bar mat bar)
     '(cat bank mat bank)
     '(cat bass mat boss))
```

Comment: which does not work correctly. (compare-using-wildcards '(?x ?x) '(nil t)) -> t instead of nil

Comment: Isn't `zip` like [`every`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm)? Also, destructively changing the `&rest` argument list is dangerous and not portable, as it may be **the** same list that was given to an [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm).

Comment: @wvxvw, from CLHS of every: predicate---a designator for a function of as many arguments as there are sequences.

Comment: @wvxvw, the lack of correctness is the worse tradeoff when dealing with such generic use functions. But you could do something at the head of `zip` like `#-(or <lisp-impl-that-conses-&rest> <another> <yet-another> ...) (setf lists (copy-list lists))`.

Comment: @wvxvw, where did you get that 1% statistic? And how much critical code depends on it, if you will? I'll always prefer the safe way until proven (e.g. profiling) that there's a need to optimize. Anyway, modifying a `&rest` list is not portable. Specifically, the burden is on functions to not rely on it being freshly consed nor modify it, as it may be a constant, see CLHS [apply](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm). You could have `zip` copy the list and call a `zip-internal` that assumes it takes a fresh list.

Comment: @wvxvw (cont, character limit) The users of `zip-internal` (or better named `%zip-fast`) at least would get a hint from the name that it makes some kind of assumption or trade for speed.